# Extjs - how can I add subtotal/summary for each Grid Grouping row?

Tags: extjs, modx

Using an ExtJS 3.4 grid, how can I achieve the neat sub-total row under every Grouped section as in the following example:

http://dev.sencha.com/playpen/gxt/totals/

I'm unable to upgrade as 3.4 is the version used by the CMS I use (MODX).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, the same example is given for 3.4:

http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-3.4.0/examples/grid/totals.html

Comment: Neither of your links works any more. You should always post code.

Comment: http://svn.geoext.org/ext/3.4.0/examples/grid/totals.html - current link